# ¿Por qué la gráfica no aparece?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, animación, qmainwindow

Estoy haciendo un programa donde la temperatura se gráfica de manera dinámica en una ventana, no logro que el programa lea la función Temperatura o usar la función Figure.

Ya intenté hacer que la clase MainWindow recibiera a la función temperatura pero me mandaba el error de 'Temperatura is not defined' por lo que la saqué de esa clase.

La función FuncAnimation no reconoce 'fig' a pesar de ya estar declarada en la misma clase

Este programa es una adaptación de otro por lo que funcionaba antes de intentar poner MainWindow ¿Como puedo solucionar?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import time
import random

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)


        self.bt1 = QPushButton("prueba 1", self)

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        xs = []
        ys = []

    #Funcion que se llama de manera peri[odica
    def animate(i, xs, ys):

        #Agrega Valores
        temp_c = round(Temperatura(),2)

        #Agrega valores a las listas
        xs.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
        ys.append(temp_c)

        #Limita las listas
        xs = xs[-20:]
        ys = ys[-20:]

        #Traza las listas
        ax.clear()
        ax.plot(xs,ys)

        #Formato
        plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)
        plt.title('Temperatura tiempo')
        plt.ylabel('Temperatura')

    #Llama a la funcion de manera periodica
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(xs,ys),interval=1000)
    plt.show()
    
    layout0 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    
    layout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    layout1.addWidget(plt)
    
    layout2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    layout2.addWidget(bt1)
    
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(layout0)
    layout0.addLayout(layout1)
    layout0.addLayout(layout2)
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)
    
    
#simulador de temperatura
def Temperatura():
    while(True):
        r=random.random()*100
    #   print(r)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        return r
    
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Temperatura()
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El principal problema es que si quieres embeber matplotlib en PyQt5 entonces no debes usar pyplot sino un FigureCanvas como muestra el [ejemplo oficial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html). Ademas si quieres mostrar una ventana de PyQt5 entonces debes usar el metodo `show()` ya que por defecto las ventanas estan ocultas.

Considerando lo anterior entonces la solución es:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import datetime as dt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


import time
import random


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.bt1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("prueba 1", self)

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 3))

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        fmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

        self.format_plot()

        xs = []
        ys = []

        layout0 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        layout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(self.canvas)

        layout2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout2.addWidget(self.bt1)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout0)
        layout0.addLayout(layout1)
        layout0.addLayout(layout2)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.fig, self.animate, fargs=(xs, ys), interval=1000
        )

    def animate(self, i, xs, ys):
        temp_c = round(generate_temperature(), 2)

        xs.append(dt.datetime.now())
        ys.append(temp_c)

        xs = xs[-20:]
        ys = ys[-20:]

        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(xs, ys)

        self.format_plot()

        return (self.ax,)

    def format_plot(self):
        self.fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45, ha="right")
        self.ax.set_title("Temperatura tiempo")
        self.ax.set_ylabel("Temperatura")
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.30)


# simulador de temperatura
def generate_temperature():
    r = random.random() * 100
    return r


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, también me aclaraste varias dudas